# Sending a data from tabhost child activity to parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I want to pass the data from `child activity` to `parent activity` in a `tabhost` and fire an onclick event for a button from `tabHost` parent activity

As a result I could send the data from parent activity `(data from TabActivity1+ data from TabActivity2)` to some new activity.

---

**Schematically i have represented the scenario below**::

[image]

**How to achieve this ??**

Answer (score 0):

To call any method from the parent activity use this code:

```
((PARENT_CLASS_NAME)getParent()).METHOD_NAME();
```

Hope this is what you want!